# How to Query Icollections of Entity Framework Code First Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I'm following this post [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/don%E2%80%99t-use-linq%E2%80%99s-join-navigate)

**his code looks like so**

```
from p in ctx.Persons
where p.ID == personId
select new PersonInfo
{
    Name = p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName,
    BornIn = p.BornInCity.Name,
    LivesIn = p.LivesInCity.Name,
    Gender = p.Sex.Name,
    CarsOwnedCount = p.Cars.Count(),
}
```

- Now when he is using p.LivesInCity.Name ( My Assumption is that he has 2 different ViewModels Classes and 1 of them has an IEnumerable or some sort of collection of City names?)

**Question**

- How can he access `p.LivesInCity.Name` but when i Try `p.Countys.[CountyColectionForSections].[SectionProperty]` I get *See Image Below*

[image]

**here is how i setup my ViewModels**

- Table 1

  ```
  public string Client { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<dbProspect> Prospects { get; set; }
  ```
- Table 2

  ```
  public int Prospect { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<dbCounty> Countys { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<UserProfiles> UserProfiles { get; set; }
  ```
- Table 3...

*Table 3 Would have a collection of another table, and table 4 would have another colection and so on* Basically a Table Hierarchy about 15 deep.

**here is how i try and access them**

```
var x = from c in db.Client
        select new ViewModelExcelReport 
        {
             client = c.ClientName,
             cntyCounty = p.Countys. //Here is where i would like to say p.Countys.[CountyProperty]
             sctSection = p.Countys.[CountyColectionForSections].[SectionProperty]
        }
```

Comment: `Countys` is a collection on `Person`. Intellisense is displaying extension methods for `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean with *`Countys` is a Collection On `Person`* I don't have any Person in here to have a collection of.

Comment: What's the relation of `Countys` to `Client`?

Comment: `Person` is the entity in the first code example of your question. I see you are referencing a different entity in your last example. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: `Client` -> ea Client has collectinOf `Prospects` -> ea Prospect has collectinOf `Countys`

Comment: Oh sorry about that `Person` is form the Link i shared. The one I am modeling my code after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following if you expect only one County per `Client` and I'm guessing at the relation between the entities:

```
var x = from c in db.Client
        from p in c.Prospects
        from ct in p.Countys
        select new ViewModelExcelReport 
        {
             client = c.ClientName,
             cntyCounty = ct.County,
             sctSection = ct.Section
        };
```

Comment: I see your comment now about the relation. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first example works because he's only referencing a single instance of an entity (LivesIn of type City), and then referencing a single primitive value within (Name property is just a string).

I see you're trying to project a new type by referencing an IEnumerable (Countys), but you never actually enumerate/iterate/materialize an instance.

p.Countys.[CountyProperty] will never exist, because you have a reference to a collection and you must get a reference to a single object first. You can do that by using Countys.Single() or SingleOrDefault() but I doubt that's what you want. I think what you want is to traverse the model in the opposite direction. From the "Many" side to the "One" side. Something like this:

```
var x = from c in db.County
    select new ViewModelExcelReport 
    {
         County = c.Name,
         CountyProperty = c.AnyProperty,
         Section = c.Section.Name,
         Prospect = c.Prospect.Name,
         Client = c.Prospect.Client.Name
    }
```